# namespace error in using getline() function in main()

Tags: c++, namespaces

I am getting an error on compiling this code. I have include namespace at the top but still, it is confusing me. (P.S I am new to this namespace thing)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;


#define MAX_HASH_CODE   10000

/* Function prototypes */

int Hash(string s, int maxCode);

#define Multiplier -1664117991L     // Multiplier used in Hash function

int Hash(string s, int maxCode)
{
    unsigned long hashcode = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) 
        hashcode = hashcode * Multiplier + s[i];
   return (hashcode % maxCode);
}

int main ()
{
    cout << "Please enter your name: ";
    string name = getLine();

    int hashcode = Hash(name, MAX_HASH_CODE);
    cout << "The hash code for your name is " << hashcode << "." <<endl;

    return 0;
}
```

error: 'getLine' was not declared in this scope
  string name = getLine();

Comment: `std` does not provide a free-standing function `getLine()`. Did you mean [`std::getline()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline). C++ is case-sensitive. Btw. `std::getline()` has to be used with arguments.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It should be something like this :

```
int main ()
{
    string name;
    cout << "Please enter your name: ";
    getline(cin, name); // As previously stated, getline() is case sensitive and requires arguments - like this.

    int hashcode = Hash(name, MAX_HASH_CODE);
    cout << "The hash code for your name is " << hashcode << "." <<endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Yeah, I just felt I was repeating the other comment.

Comment: getline() required arguments. Thanks!